# Changing dafault Netbeans Platform

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

Im developing application on top of Netbeans Platform.

In NetBeans IDE it is possible to choose different Netbeans Platform (it can be added under
NetBeans Platform Manager), but i cant find option/property to change default selection.
Is this even supported on Netbeans IDE?

Comment: You can set the platform for your project in project properties dialog under 'Libraries' branch. Not sure if that's what you after though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for ANT based Nb Platform application is to modify ant build file to create custom properties before building application (separate modules). In this solution I create new properties file and fix the pointer in platform properties file to point to it. This file is later imported before building each module.

1) Create/Modify platform-private.properties to set user.properties.file to your custom one (i.e  nbproject/private/build.properties). This file is later used to configure properties when building separate modules.

2) Create new user.properties.file (build.properties) and set nbplatform.default.harness.dir and nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir to correct values (those parameters points to folder where nb platform is located - in my case it is located in project basedir under ./nbrc folder)

```
<project name="..." basedir=".">

<!-- Basedir property must be converted to use forward slashes (for windows machines) -->
<path id="basedir.path">
    <pathelement path="${basedir}" />
</path>
<pathconvert targetos="unix" property="basedir.unix" refid="basedir.path"/>

<!-- Initialize path to netbeans platform [located in nbrc folder in project root directory -->
<mkdir dir="nbproject/private"/>
<echo file="nbproject/private/platform-private.properties">user.properties.file=${basedir.unix}/nbproject/private/build.properties${line.separator}</echo>
<echo file="nbproject/private/build.properties">nbplatform.default.harness.dir=${nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir}/harness${line.separator}</echo>
<echo file="nbproject/private/build.properties" append="true">nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir=${basedir.unix}/nbrc${line.separator}  </echo>


<!-- .. -->

</project>  `
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do this using the default ant based system. However if you use the maven based approach then it is a simple as editing the pom.xml